# PHP DOM XML - Create Multiple Namespace Attributes?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm working on some PHP to create XML from a database using the DOM extension.

Basically, I need to create a NameSpace and add 3 attributes to it:

```
<NameSpaceName xmlns="uri:xxx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="uri:xxx">
```

The full code i've written is below:

```
include_once("includes/connect.php");

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM tableName");
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());


// create a new XML document
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

// create root node
$root = $doc->createElementNS('uri:xxx', 'PayerRecords');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);
$root->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$root->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xsi:schemaLocation', 'uri:xxx');

// process one row at a time
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

  // add node for each row
  $occ = $doc->createElement('Content');
  $occ = $root->appendChild($occ);

  // add a child node for each field
  foreach ($row as $fieldname => $fieldvalue) {

    $child = $doc->createElement($fieldname);
    $child = $occ->appendChild($child);

    $value = $doc->createTextNode($fieldvalue);
    $value = $child->appendChild($value);

  } // foreach

} // while

// get completed xml document
$xml_string = $doc->saveXML();

echo $xml_string;
```

But when I execute the above I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'DOMException' with message 'Namespace
>   Error' in
>   xml.php:21
>   Stack trace: #0
>   xml.php(21):
>   DOMElement->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.o...', 'xsi:schemaLocat...',
>   'uri:xxx...') #1 {main} thrown
>   in
>   xml.php
>   on line 21

Line 21 is the second 'setAttributeNS' line.

Can anyone see where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

schemaLocation is not declared in the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/` but in `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`

```
<?php
// create a new XML document
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
// create root node
$root = $doc->createElementNS('http://xxx', 'PayerRecords');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);
$root->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$root->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'schemaLocation', 'http://xxx');

echo $doc->savexml();
```

prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PayerRecords xmlns="http://xxx" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xxx"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I didn't quite get it the first time so I'm posting my answer in more detail. Maybe someone finds this helpful.

```
// create DOM document
$xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

// create root element
$el = $xml->createElementNS('http://namespaceA/url/here/', 'rootelement');

// to be able to add new namespaces we must first add namespace 'xsi'
// third parameter is important (use your main namespace with .xsd)
$root->setAttributeNS(
  'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
  'xsi:schemaLocation',
  'http://namespaceA/url/here/ http://namespaceA/xsdfile/here.xsd');

// add new namespace
$el->setAttributeNS(
  'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/',
  'xmlns:namespaceB',
  'http://namespaceB/url/here/');

// add root element to DOM
$xml->appendChild($el);
```

This mail archive message was very helpful: http://www.mail-archive.com/php-general@lists.php.net/msg135362.html.

Answer (score 2):

replace line 21 with

```
$root->setAttributeNS(
  'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 
  'xsi:schemaLocation',
  'http://xxx http://xxx/xxx.xsd'
);
```

`xsi:schemaLocation` is not defined in the http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/ or your namespace, but in `xsi`. so you have to use the (complete) `xsi` namespace uri as the first parameter.

and: you don't need to call `setAttributeNS()` twice: the single line above generates both the `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` and `xsi:schemaLocation="http://xxx http://xxx/xxx.xsd"` attributes.