# Zend Framework sitemap validation

Tags: xml, validation, zend-framework, sitemap

When outputting Zend Navigation using `sitemap()` view helper, I get the following error:

```
Sitemap is invalid according to XML Schema at "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"
```

The validation is turned on:

```
$this->navigation()->setUseSchemaValidation(true)->setFormatOutput(true);
```

- **How to render valid xml sitemap using Zend Framework?**

My sitemap looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/index/index/slug/news</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/strona/test-page</loc>
  </url>
  <url>

    <loc>http://example.com/strona/test-submenu</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/strona/subpage-submenu</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/strona/test-submenu-1</loc>

  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/feed/list</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/default/sitemap</loc>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Precondition*:
DomDocument::schemaValidate($path) won't work until [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/de/filesystem.configuration.php) is enabled

*About Sitemaps*:
From http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#validating

> In order to validate your Sitemap or
>   Sitemap index file against a schema,
>   the XML file will need additional
>   headers as shown below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"
        xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      ...
   </url>
</urlset>
```

to add those headers to your XML you first need to retrieve the DomDocument via `$domDoc = $this->sitemap()->getDomSitemap()`
than add the additional headers and finally `echo $domDoc->saveXml()`

doesnt seem nice to me to do so much in your view, maybe an additional ViewHelper subclassing Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Sitemap may be appropriate for you.

Unfortunately I have never worked with DomDocument yet, so I can't help with setting the namespace attributes, maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236931/php-dom-xml-create-multiple-namespace-addtributes) will help you for that.

Comment: Thanks. I've added those headers, but I was still getting the same error. The issue was that `setUseSchemaValidation()` requires `allow_url_fopen` directive to be enabled, which is off by default on my production server.

Comment: happy to help, i'll add your hint to my answer. interestingly i somehow overread this dependency in the php manual